# Challenge "One number per line" at VimGolf: How does the #82 solution work?

Tags: vim

The 82-th solution of the [challenge](http://vimgolf.com/challenges/56fb2e75ccffcc0009026473) contains a fragment like the following:

```
V"=[<C-R><C-A>]<CR>p
```

I think here `V` enters the likewise visual mode, and then the help document says that

```
    When typing the '=' after " or CTRL-R the cursor moves to the command-line,
where you can enter any expression (see |expression|).  All normal
command-line editing commands are available, including a special history for
expressions.  When you end the command-line by typing <CR>, Vim computes the
result of the expression.  If you end it with <Esc>, Vim abandons the
expression.  If you do not enter an expression, Vim uses the previous
expression (like with the "/" command).
```

Then I am confused: is that expression ended by an enter, and hence looks like `[`, following which we press `ctrl-a`?

If I repeat the sequence as above, some weird behavior happens that I don't think is what is intended. So I must have missed something important.

Thanks in advance for any help or reference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `"=` will evaluate the given expression, if you `p(paste)` the evaluated result would be converted into string. If you read the doc further, you will see:

> The expression must evaluate to a String.  A Number is always automatically
>   converted to a String.  For the "p" and ":put" command, if the result is a
>   Float it's converted into a String.  If the result is a List each element is
>   turned into a String and used as a line.  A Dictionary or FuncRef results in
>   an error message (use string() to convert).

`<c-r><c-a>` will fill the `WORD` under cursor.

So the expression is `[---...---2,3,5,..]` what is this expression? It is a list. And as doc told us, when you `p` to paste, it will be converted into lines.

What is tricky here is the first element in the list, the `-------...-2`,

We have:

```
   2 -> 2
  -2 -> -2
 --2 -> 2
---2 -> -2
.....
```

Now you can count, how many `-` before the `2`, I think it must be even number. so we have `2` in first line, after you pasted.

I hope that now you understood it better.

Comment: Ah! I got it!  

I missed that the two non-printing characters are `ctrl-r` and `ctrl-a`, rather than `enter` and `ctrl-a`!
Thanks for explaining the expression register. This is a great lesson from only 14 keystrokes :D

Comment: I was also astonished by this ingenuity as well. :P